# Using MySQL IGNORE on one column under certain conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I want to import records from Gmail into a table, and I do not need duplicates for each account.

**Description:**

I have a table named list with definition below:

```
id int(11),
account_id int(11),
email varchar(255),
phone varchar(30),
primary key(id),
FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts (id)
```

This table holds records for different accounts and an email can be considered valid for two or more accounts. This means that an email can repeat in a table but can only appear once for each account_id.

I imported my contacts from Gmail (which is above 700 contacts and other users may have more than that).

**The challenge:**

I have an option of running two queries (one to check if email or phone exists, the second to insert record) for each record which in my case is 1,400 SQL queries to enable me insert all imported records, ensuring there are no duplicates for each account_id in the list table.

I have looked at MySQL IGNORE and similar keywords like ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but they do not seem to work in this scenario as I cannot make the email and phone columns unique as they can contain duplicate content.

What is the best way of inserting these 700 records ensuring that the email and phone are not repeated for each account_id without having to run 1,400 queries?

**QUESTION UPDATE:**

I do not think INSERT IGNORE CAN WORK HERE FOR THE FOLLOWING REASONS:

1. I cannot make email and phone unique columns
2. The phone number may be empty but with an email entry, this may break the unique pattern

**QUESTION ILLUSTRATION**

I have two offices using the table to store their customer records. Someone can be a customer to both offices. This means his record can appear twice in the table but can only appear once for each account_id in the table.
The challenge now is to insert several records into the table ensuring that a record does not repeat for each account_id.

Comment: I'm a little confused -- option of running 700 queries or 1400 -- why?  You can bring all the results into one table, and then run a single insert statement into your account table to match your needs.

Comment: how do i ensure that there are no duplicates for each account_id in the table?

Comment: Where is your data coming from?  Do you have a text file you're trying to run with 700 insert statements?  Or are those 700 rows already in a table and you're just trying to get some/all/subset of them to the account table?

Comment: I imported from Gmail and have my data in an array.

Comment: IMHO you have to illustrate your question with relevant sample data with duplicates in emails and phone numbers per account_id and desired output. That might help you get your answer faster. Right now it's unclear what you want to do if there are duplicate emails but different phone numbers per account_id and vice versa. What should go to the target table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not very clear to me, but it looks very much like you just need to add some two-columns unique constraints.

- an `email` must be unique for one given `account_id`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE (account_id, email);
```

- a `phone number` must be unique for one given `account_id`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE (account_id, phone);
```

Both indexes may exist at the same time on your table. Either could raise a "duplicate-key violation" error, and would trigger the `IGNORE` or the `ON DUPLICATE` clauses of your insertions.

---

That being said, there is an issue in your structure. You are about to duplicate your customers' details for each `account_id` they are in business with.

You should have a `customers` table that contains all your customer's contact details (and only that), another `accounts` table -- your "offices", if I understand it right -- and finally one relation table to model the [n-n relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) between `customers` and `accounts`:

```
CREATE TABLE customers_accounts (
    customer_id INT NOT NULL,
    account_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, account_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(id)
    FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id)
);
```

Comment: +1 . . . Even though I've never seen "unicity" used in this context.  Did you consider "uniqueness"?

Comment: Having checked the definition of "unicity" in English (vs. "unicité" in French), my wording was indeed quite amusing :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You had the answer: use "INSERT IGNORE" but what you probably didn't do is add a composite unique index (mentioned by RamdomSeed above), and/or set blank fields to NULL.

1) Create composite index, using the account id. This means that the email must be unique for that user.

ADD UNIQUE(account_id, email)

2) Regarding the phone "may be blank" set this to NULL when blank. Unique indexes ignore NULLS. (A small gotcha, but probably plays in your favour here, and why it's like that. You can then also add

ADD UNIQUE(account_id, phone)

(Aside: general advice is that you don't usually have multiple uniques on a table as it can get confusing and messy, but it might be what you need and it's fine - so long as you can handle the logic)

Comment: +1 for mentionning that `NULL` values are ignored by UNIQUE constraints. `NULL` is equal to nothing, not even to `NULL` (try `SELECT NULL = NULL;`).

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you're using a scripting language (php seems to be popular with mysql) to store an array of contacts from gmail?

If so, this insert statement will insert the record if the account id doesn't exist in the table already -- this uses an Outer Join with a Null check, but you can also use Not In or Not Exists as well:

```sql
Insert Into YourTable (Id, AccountId, Email, Phone)
Select t.Id, t.AccountId, t.Email, t.Phone
From (Select 1 Id, 1 AccountId, 'someemail' Email, 'somephone' Phone) t
    Left Join YourTable t2 On t.AccountId = t2.AccountId
Where t2.AccountId Is Null
```

EDIT:

Assuming I'm understanding the comments, then just add to the Outer Join:

```sql
Insert Into YourTable (Id, AccountId, Email, Phone)
Select t.Id, t.AccountId, t.Email, t.Phone
From (Select 1 Id, 1 AccountId, 'someemail' Email, 'somephone' Phone) t
    Left Join YourTable t2 On t.AccountId = t2.AccountId
        And (t.email = t2.email Or t.phone = t2.phone)
Where t2.AccountId Is Null
```

This should ensure no accounts get reinserted if they have a matching phone or email.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. How do I perform a multi row insert with the query

Comment: @OguguaBelonwu -- it was my impression you were looping through 700 records in your array, no?  Just replace the values above with a prepared statement.

Comment: Please, kindly give an example with 2 records to enable me get a clearer view on how to concatenate the prepared statement

Comment: kindly check my update. account_id is not unique on the table; rather each email/phone must be unique for each account_id in the list table.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could use [INSERT IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) assuming AccountId is your unique identifier:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table
SET field = someValue,
    anotherfield = someothervalue
```

If however you can have the same accounts with multiple emails, then this may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: To further buttress the problem, the email/phone cannot be made unique because the column should support duplicate emails but unique to each account_id in the table.

Comment: @OguguaBelonwu -- so the account id isn't unique.  If that's the case, you are correct, this solution won't help.  Look at the other post -- looks useful for this scenario.  Best regards.

Comment: No, account_id isn't unique either as you can have several records for each account

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert Into YourTable (Id, Account_Id, Email, Phone)
Select a.id, a.Account_Id, a.Email, a.Phone
From (Select t.id, t.Account_Id,  t.Email,  t.Phone from t
   group by account_id,email,phone )a;
```

Suggest to import the records into a temp table (t). Then only filter the records into another table (yourtable) ie remove the duplicate as you like.